# React router dom how to set activeStyle to NavLink by default to all current or active links

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple **Navigation** component that I created like this below:

```
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavLink exact to="/" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/about" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>About</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/contact" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Contact</NavLink>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Everything works fine when I try to navigate to the `URL` and it renders the expected **component** and it also **changes** the **style** of the **link** but How can I refactor or minimize the code of `activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}` that is being **redundant** cause if I have more **links** or **routes** this will be a complete mess.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: React router injects `class='active'` into the link element. It'll become something like `<a href='/about'  class="active">About</a>`. You can use CSS to style links that has `active` class.

Comment: So you're saying that the `class='active'` comes out of the box already when the link becomes the current url and I would just take care of the css and that's it?

Comment: Yes. You can see it in the Chrome inspector. It is also documented here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md